# How to iterate List of one object array and set to another object list in java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Currently I have list of object(Entitlement) array, from that array I have to Iterate and add to the list of Card object, any way to do this. Please let me know.

Now I don't want entire data from entitlements list, need only id and name and want this to be store into Card object.
How i can achieve this, using stream?

```
public static class Entitlement {
   public String id;
   public String name;
   public String serviceEntitlementNumber;
   public String serviceType;
   public String alphaId;
   public String modifiedTime;
} //Entitlement obj – 


public static class Card { 
   public String id;
   public String name;
} // card obj

List <MerchantGatewayEntitlement> entitlements = 
       getEntitlements(merchantId);

List <Card> cards = new ArrayList <>();
 
for (MerchantGatewayEntitlement entitlement : entitlements) {
     how to add this list to card list.
}
```

Comment: Look into Stream with .map.  that will allow you to take list of one kind of object and map it (turn it) into a list of another type of object

Comment: public static class Entitlement {
public String id;
public String name;
public String serviceEntitlementNumber;
public String serviceType;
public String alphaId;
public String modifiedTime;
}

public static class Card {
public String id;
public String name;
}
List <MerchantGatewayEntitlement> entitlements = getEntitlements(merchantId);
List <Card> cards = new ArrayList <>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use streams?  It has its advantages but it also has quite a bit of overhead. Nothing wrong with using a loop.  And don't worry about `"improving"` existing `working code` using Java 8 features.

I don't know what your `Card` class looks like but there is nothing wrong with the following:

```
List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<>();
for (MerchantGatewayEntitlement entitlement : entitlements) {
   cardList.add(new Card(entitlement.getCard(), entitlement.getSomethingElse()));
}
```

or other Java 8 options.

```
entitlements.forEach(ent-> {
    cardList.add(new Card(ent.getCard(), ent.getSomethingElse()));
});
```

But if you insist on using a stream solution and you need to be able to `modify` the returned list, then do it like this.

```
List<Card> cardList = entitlements.stream()
     .map(ent -> new 
         Card(ent.getCard(),ent.getSomethingElse()))
     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: public static class Entitlement { public String id; public String name; public String serviceEntitlementNumber; public String serviceType; public String alphaId; public String modifiedTime; } //Entitlement obj

Comment: public static class Card { public String id; public String name; } List <MerchantGatewayEntitlement> entitlements = getEntitlements(merchantId); List <Card> cards = new ArrayList <>(); // card obj

Comment: @SujataKattimani I added your classes to the question so you can delete your comments.

Answer (score 2):

To create a `List` of `Card` objects from the other `List`, you can use `Stream#map`.

```java
List<Card> cards = entitlements.stream().map(e -> new Card(e.getId(), e.getName())).toList();
```

If you want to add to an existing `List`, an enhanced `for` loop or `List#forEach` would be appropriate.